# Angular 2 service method calling - self.context.dummySer.foo is not a function

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to call a service method from a component, but I keep getting this error: self.context.dummySer.foo is not a function

UPDATE:

Since the solutions worked for other components but not for this one and it just doesn't make any sense, I'll just copy paste the real "not working component" and service.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
...stuff
import { UrlifyService } from '../services/urlify.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editar-noticias',
  templateUrl: 'editar-noticias.component.html'
})

export class EditarNoticiasComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  ...stuff


  constructor(
    ...stuff
    public urlifySer: UrlifyService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
   ...stuff
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
   ...stuff
  }

  ...other methods

  public urlify(titulo:string){
    this.urlifySer.urlify(titulo);
  }

}
```

View:

```
<input type="text" #titulo (blur)="urlify(titulo.value)">
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UrlifyService {

  urlified: string;

  constructor() { }

  urlify(str) {
    str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    str = str.toLowerCase();

    let from = "àáäâèéëêìíïîòóöôùúüûñç·/_,:;";
    let to   = "aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuunc------";
    for (let i=0, l=from.length ; i<l ; i++) {
      str = str.replace(new RegExp(from.charAt(i), 'g'), to.charAt(i));
    }

    str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '')
      .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
      .replace(/-+/g, '-');

    this.urlified = str;
  }

}
```

The method takes the title value and it builds a friendly url from it. As I said, calling the same method the same way from other components works... but for some reason, it just doesn't on this one.

Comment: It should work https://plnkr.co/edit/MYid4Kacl6eymyJ1Ih7H?p=preview

Comment: Try `constructor(public dummySer: DummyService) {console.log(dummySer);}`

Comment: It logs the service correctly. Still it doesn't work in the view...

Comment: Can you reproduce it on a plunker? Are you using AOT compiation?

Comment: It is difficult to implement on a plunker since it is a production project with database stuff. I updated the question with the real component and service though.

Comment: Where do you provide `UrlifyService`? In root NgModule?

Comment: Try to put `debugger` as follows `public urlify(titulo:string){ debugger;...` and observe console. It still works for me

Comment: Yeah, inside @NgModule, providers array

Comment: Turns out that the problem was elsewhere. A misspell in an initial value taken from the same service for the the input. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's considered a bad practice to directly call the service from your HTML binding, prefer using a method in your Component to handle this call. It will, by the way, fix your problem.

Your code would became:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'whatever',
  templateUrl: 'whatever.html'
})
export class whateverComponent {
    constructor(public dummySer: DummyService) {}

    public dummyMethod(text: string) {
        this.dummySer.foo(text);
    } 
}
```

And in your html you would call the dummyMethod instead of your service.

Also, I noticed that they weren't any exported class in your component, did you just removed it to show us your code or was it the original code? The error could be there too.

Comment: I didn't know that was bad practice. Calling a method to call a method felt redundant... but anyway, I'll do it that way from now on.
It doesn't solve the problem though, the error just changes to "this.dummySer.foo is not a function".
The weirdest thing is that calling the same service the same way from another component works.

Comment: You have to separate each responsibility/module, your service is only here to retrieve data and your component is there to display data. Your component retrieves the data to display, not your HTML. Otherwise, update in your code would be a pain. Also, it allows you to easily add more process on your code.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Sakuto answer, defining the method in component will do your work.

Component:

```
constructor(private dummySer: DummyService) {}

foo(text) {
  this.dummySer.foo(text);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" #text (blur)="foo(text.value)">
```

Note: Mark your service private in constructor.

Comment: Maybe you should write `this.dummySer.foo` instead of just `dummySer.foo`

Comment: As I told Sakuto, this solution only changes the error to "this.dummySer.foo is not a function". But the weirdest thing is that another component with identical code to call the service works this way...